# Can XNA & Visual Studio be run in VMWare Fusion on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, vmware-fusion, xna

Is it possible to run XNA & Visual Studio from a machine under VMWare Fusion running on Mac OS X?

(I'm currently attempting to install this and try it out - we'll see if it works or not in a few hours I guess. Thought I could save time if it doesn't. :)

Comment: Visual Studio works fine. No experience with XNA though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my experience, VS can run properly on VMWare Fusion and I wrote some .NET apps with it. However I am not very sure about XNA. the possibility is 'too slow', I think. Referring to [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/18059.aspx),

> VMWare does not emulate a Shader Model
>   1.1 card - XNA needs a Shader model 1.1 card. There's no software rendering in XNA/DirectX - you used to
>   be able to create the reference
>   rasterizer which is optimized for
>   correctness not speed but its
>   essentially useless as a debugging
>   tool. Even the simplest game will run
>   too slow to work.

also another topic [here](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/220677)

Comment: That information is obsolete. VMWare Fusion supports Shader Model 3 now.

Comment: @stimpy77 Feel free to add another answer with links and/or sources.